# Length of time for naturalization after getting married while in possession of a green card

Tags: usa, citizenship, greencard

I was told that marrying an American would get you a green card sooner and that you can apply for naturalization in 3 years after getting the green card. However, with an employer green card, the naturalization would happen 5 years later.

How long would one have to wait if they got their green card from their employer and married an American citizen? Would they have to wait for 5 or 3 years before applying for naturalization?

Answer (score 6):

You're eligible to apply for naturalization if you were a green card holder for 5 years, or if you were a green card holder *and* married to a US citizen for 3 years.

How you got the green card doesn't matter. But to qualify for the 3-years eligibility period you have to be *both* married to the US citizen spouse *and* have a green card for the 3 years preceding the application. You cannot, for example, marry a US citizen 3 years after getting a green card based on your employment and then immediately apply for naturalization.

See [the USCIS eligibility tool](https://www.uscis.gov/citizenship-resource-center/learn-about-citizenship/naturalization-eligibility) for details.